# Is it possible to know if the function is called from within eval() in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

I am looking to come up with a function which will return based on how it is called.

If I call the function from within a php class or function, it will return an array, whereas if it was called from within an `eval()` statement then it will return a string.

Say the function is as:

```
function GetName(){
    return isEval ? 'John Doe' : array('John','Doe');
}
```

Is it possible to replace the isEval with something to detect if it was called from within `eval()` ?

Update:
This is going to be part of a CMS system. I need to provide some already builtin functions to become available publicly. I know the security risks would arise using eval(), but still would like to know if it is possible in anyway.

Passing in parameter for sure works perfectly, but as described above, dont want to get abused by providing that option.

Comment: I think its easiest to pass a parameter : `function GetName($format)`

Comment: If you give the bigger picture, I'm pretty sure there's a way to avoid both the function returning two different values and using eval altogether.

Comment: I am not sure about it but I am pretty sure that you shouldn't be using `eval()`.

Comment: just updated the question with regards to the comments. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only function that contains information you want is `debug_backtrace`. So you can do something like:

```
function getName(){
    $debug = debug_backtrace();

    //check $debug array. I think it should
    //be in the 2nd element of array:
    if ($debug[1]['function'] == 'eval') { 
       //Do Eval stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an argument in your function? True if eval, false if not.

```
function GetName(eval){
    if(eval)
       //TODO IF EVAL
    else
       //TODO IF NOT EVAL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling from `eval` pass `true` as parameter, following function should work.

```
function GetName(isEval = false){
    return isEval ? 'John Doe' : array('John','Doe');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the two answers here already, suggesting passing an argument to the function, it got me thinking about overloading the function, so you could personally pass it another argument to show that it isn't being passed via an `eval()` but of course [PHP doesn't support function overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

*However* you could write your function to accept an optional parameter, then use func_num_args() and func_get_arg() to determine what has been sent. If the optional parameter isn't being sent, you could easily and safely assume that it is being `eval()`'ed and you can make it act accordingly.

Comment: The problem is I dont want to make any kind of assumption. PLB's solution works perfectly for this case. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @code90 Yeah, I upvoted his answer before you accepted it, I didn't know you could do that - hence I also +fav'ed this question as I learned something useful that I can refer back to later.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEval()
{
    foreach(array_reverse(debug_backtrace()) as $v) {
        return $v['function'] === 'eval';
    }
}

function isEval() { // updated by code90
    foreach(array_reverse(debug_backtrace()) as $v) {
        if($v['function'] === 'eval') return true;
    }

    return false; }


function myFunc()
{
    return isEval() ? "is eval\n" : "is not eval\n";
}

function callAnotherFunction()
{
    return myFunc();
}

function myFunctionWithEval()
{
    eval('$return = myFunc();');
    return $return;
}
```

Test

```
echo "myFunc() without eval: " . myFunc();
eval("echo 'myFunc() whit eval: ' . myFunc();");

echo "callAnotherFunction() without eval: " . callAnotherFunction();
eval("echo 'callAnotherFunction() with eval: ' . callAnotherFunction();");

echo 'myFunctionWithEval() with eval: ' . myFunctionWithEval();
```

Output

```
myFunc() without eval: is not eval
myFunc() whit eval: is eval
callAnotherFunction() without eval: is not eval
callAnotherFunction() with eval: is eval
myFunctionWithEval() with eval: is not eval <--- PROBLEM!
```

myFunctionWithEval call myFunc with eval. You can not guarantee when it was called eval. Can give false positive.

You should think of another way to proceed. This methodology should **not be used**!

An alternative, but I always recommend **not to use**:

```
function isEval()
{
    return isset($GLOBALS['__MyEval']) && $GLOBALS['__MyEval'] === true;
}

function myFunc()
{
    return isEval() ? "is eval\n" : "is not eval\n";
}

function myFunctionWithEval()
{
    $GLOBALS['__MyEval'] = true;
    eval('$return = myFunc();');
    $GLOBALS['__MyEval'] = null;

    return $return;
}

echo "myFunctionWithEval() with eval: " . myFunctionWithEval();
```

Comment: myFunctionWithEval call myFunc with eval. You can not guarantee when it was called eval.can give false positive

Comment: I see your point and need to run your test code to see the problem. Seems like the function isEval() you came up with might need some improvements to detect accurately.

Comment: @code90 , I modified the post by inserting something more reliable

Comment: I just tried your original post, and slightly modified your isEval() function. 

function isEval()
{
    foreach(array_reverse(debug_backtrace()) as $v) {
        if($v['function'] === 'eval') return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

this way it worked with no problem.